# How to give the CircleAvatar an image from memory

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a CircleAvatar with a backgroundImage property to load an image took from memory but I get the error
How I can set the image.memory in the CircleAvatar  in flutter?

```
    String url = "$GetImageDataUrl/$serviceId/image";
    final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(url)).load("");
    final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
   
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: image.memory(bytes),  // get error
)
```

I can not using the image.Network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

checkout below code it may help you,

CircleAvatar widget backgroundImage property you can't assign Image type to ImageProvider.

Use **MemoryImage**

```
ByteData imageData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/test.png');
Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 30.0,
  backgroundImage: MemoryImage(bytes), //here
)
```